# python - cant find solution to IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, loops, indexing, index-error

The error is:

```
File "node2.py", line 96, in put_chains_together
    if outer_index > 0 and (chain['chain'][0]['index'] - prev_chain['chain'][-1]['index'] != 1):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
    all_chains = []
    prev_chain = {}
    for outer_index, chain in enumerate(chains_to_add):
        print('\n //// chain in chains_to_add')
        pprint(chain)
        if outer_index > 0 and (chain['chain'][0]['index'] - prev_chain['chain'][-1]['index'] != 1):
            r = requests.get("http://" + connections[len(connections) -1]['ip'] + ":" + connections[len(connections) - 1]['port'] + "/give_chain", params = {'previous': prev_chain['chain'][0]['previous_hash'], 'start_at_index':0, 'increment_by':len(prev_chain['chain']) + 1})
            chains_from_request = json.loads(r.text)
            del all_chains[-len(chains_from_request['chain'])]
            for index, ch in enumerate(chains_from_request['chain']):
                all_chains.append(ch)

        prev = {}
        for index, ch in enumerate(chain['chain']):
            deleted = False
            if index > 0 and ch['index'] == prev['index']:
                if ch['timestamp'] < prev['timestamp']:
                    del chain['chain'][index - 1]
                    deleted = True
                else:
                    del chain['chain'][index]
                    deleted = True

            if not deleted: 
                all_chains.append(ch)

            prev = ch

        prev_chain = chain
```

I can't figure out which index the error is referring to...I think it is `chain[0]['index']` because the other index is just an instruction to get the last block which shouldn't give a list index error. `chain['chain']` and `prev_chain['chain']` (just a copy of `chain['index']`) are both arrays with objects in them. Each object has an index. Thanks

Comment: You noticed that the long statement makes debugging hard. So break out the `chain['chain']` part into its own variable first. Then print its value to see that some part is probably empty when it shouldn't have been.

Comment: This likely means your list is empty.  Try printing out the length of `chain["chain"]` with `print(len(chain['chain']))`.

Comment: regardless of what variable i am logging...I can see that there is now error in there not being an index

Comment: thanks ill try your suggestion and see if it comes up empty

Comment: To @HaraldNordgren's point.  Long lines like you have here make it difficult to debug.  Take your `r = requests.get(...)` line.  I see at least 3 different places where you could have an index error there.  And you would have no way of knowing where in that line the error is occurring.  Sometimes breaking it out into more lines with more variables is worth it.  In this current example we don't know if `chain["chain"][0]` is the issue or if it's actually `prev_chain["chain"][0]`.  The answer could be _both_.  Best way to check is to print out each.

Comment: you guys are right the length of the chain is 0 when the `outer_index` is 1...weird...at least i have it narrowed to that...any other ideas?